# Failed to get request Token

Tags: android

I am creating a Twitter app to share photo to Twitpic. i have given all the details api-key, consumer key, Secret-key.
but i am not able to sign in the app. In the Logcat the folloing error is coming..

> 10-25 14:03:16.294: DEBUG/TwitterApp(780): Failed to get request token
>   10-25 14:03:16.314: WARN/System.err(780): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>   10-25 14:03:16.314: WARN/System.err(780):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
>   10-25 14:03:16.344: WARN/System.err(780):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
>   10-25 14:03:16.354: WARN/System.err(780):     at com.vikash.android.twitter.TwitterApp$2.run(TwitterApp.java:117)
>   10-25 14:03:16.384: WARN/System.err(780): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>   10-25 14:03:16.384: WARN/System.err(780):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
>   10-25 14:03:16.434: WARN/System.err(780):     at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
>   10-25 14:03:16.434: WARN/System.err(780):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
>   10-25 14:03:16.444: WARN/System.err(780):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
>   10-25 14:03:16.444: WARN/System.err(780):     ... 2 more

please help me how to short-out this problem.

regrads
Vikash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using proxy connection, try open internet connection.

Comment: ya dude i am using open connection, then also it is not working.

Comment: then post ur details code. then able to figure out the problem. thanks